# PHP Scraping using XPath - html5 issue?

Tags: php, xpath, screen-scraping

I'm attempting to scrape the value of an input box from a URL. I seem to be having problems with my implementation of XPath.

The page to be scraped looks something like:

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html lang="en">
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <div><span>Blah</span></div>
        <div><span>Blah</span> Blah</div>
        <div>
            <form method="POST" action="blah">
                <input name="SomeName" id="SomeId" value="GET ME"/>
                <input type="hidden" name="csrfToken" value="ajax:3575644127378754050" id="csrfToken-login">
            </form>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

and I'm attempting to parse it like this:

```
$Contents = file_get_contents("https://www.linkedin.com/uas/login");
$Selector = "//input[@id='csrfToken-login']/@value";
print_r($Selector);
$dom = new DOMDocument;
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$dom->loadHtml($Contents);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
libxml_use_internal_errors(false);
print_r($xpath->query($Selector));
```

NB: `dump()` just wraps `print_r()` but adds some stack trace info and formatting.

The output is as folllowws:

```
14:50:08 scraper.php 181: (Scraper->Test)
//input[@id='csrfToken-login']/@value

14:50:08 scraper.php 188: (Scraper->Test)
DOMNodeList Object
(
)
```

Which I'm assuming means it was unable to find anything in the document which matches my selector? I've tried a number of variations, jsut to see if I can get *something* back:

```
/input/@value
/input
//input
/div
```

The only selector which I've been able to get *anything* from is `/` which returns the entire document.

What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT:** As some can't reproduce the problem with the old example, I've replaced it with an almost identical example which also demonstrates the problem but uses a public URL (LinkedIn login page).

There's been a suggestion that this isn't possible due to the parser choking on html5 - (as is the internal page) anyone have any experience of this?

Comment: you cannot dump any of the DOM instances. They dont expose their properties. even if you had used the correct XPath `//input[@id='SomeId']/@value` the dump() result would show the same empty object (despite items being in there).

Comment: I've edited the Q to include a "working" example using the LinkedIn login page.

Comment: Hello! I have update my answer with working code (at least for the linkedin example)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your selector starts with a single slash(`/`), it means the absolute path from the root. You need to use double slash (`//`) which selects all matching elements regardless of their location.

print_r won't work for this. Everything was fine in your code except for actually getting value.
Lists classes in PHP usually have a property called `length`, check that instead.

```
$Contents = file_get_contents("https://www.linkedin.com/uas/login");
$Selector = "//input[@id='csrfToken-login']/@value";
$dom = new DOMDocument;
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$dom->loadHtml($Contents);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
libxml_use_internal_errors(false);
$b = $xpath->query($Selector);
echo $b->item(0)->value;
```

Comment: or provide the full path from the root

Comment: This doesn't seem to resolve my problem - have a look at the updated example

Answer (score 2):

[DOMXPath](http://www.php.net/manual/en/domxpath.query.php) looks fine to me.

As for the xpath use descendant-or-self shortcut `//` to get to the input tag

```
//input[@id='SomeId']/@value
```

Comment: Thanks but I don't think that's the only issue - I've updated the example to point at the LinkedIn login page where the same behavior is visible.

Answer (score 0):

I've been to the LinkedIn login page that you specified and it is malformed; even your pared-down example has an unclosed `input` node.  I know nothing about PHP's XPath implementation, but I'm guessing no straight XPath API is ever going to work with a malformed document.

Your XPath is correct, by the way.

You might need an intermediary step using [TagSoup](http://ccil.org/~cowan/XML/tagsoup/) to "well form" the source before you start querying it, or Google "tag soup php" for any PHP-specific solutions/implementations.

I hope this helps,
Zachary